# Could not parse the remainder: '% form.as_p %' from '% form.as_p %'

Tags: python, django

I have a error with Django:
I think everything is correct but I don't understand this error
Cloud you help me please?

Could not parse the remainder: '% form.as_p %' from '% form.as_p %'

```
    <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method = 'post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{% form.as_p %}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the percents in the form tag `{{% form.as_p %}}`

It should be `{{ form.as_p }}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options

Comment: how can I do it? could you help me please?

Comment: today I tried to ask another question but stackoverflow didn't allow

Comment: I'm fairly new myself but I believe there should be a checkmark symbol next to people's answers. It's probably greyed out and you hover and click on the answer you believe to be the best answer to your question.